SwiftUI ScrollView ignores scroll position when appending element at the beginning
I’m implementing functionality to dynamically append elements to a ScrollView when the user swipes to the edges. Adding elements to the end of the list works as expected, but I encounter an issue when adding elements to the beginning. Specifically, if I attempt to navigate to the previous element via a button (before swiping to any other element after startup), the ScrollView scrolls to position -2 instead of -1 when tapping the "swipe left" button.
This is my attempt:
struct ListTabView2: View {
    
    private enum ScrollViewAppender {
        case previous, next, none
    }
    
    @State private var scrollPosition: Int? = 0 {
        didSet {
            print(scrollPosition ?? "nil")
        }
    }
    @State private var elements: [Int] = Array(0..<5) {
        didSet {
            print(elements)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Button {
                moveScrollPosition(by: -1)
            } label: {
                Text("swipe left")
            }
            Spacer()
            Button {
                moveScrollPosition(by: 1)
            } label: {
                Text("swipe right")
            }
        }
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0, content: {
                    ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(.blue)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(height: 300)
                            .padding(.leading, proxy.safeAreaInsets.leading)
                            .padding(.trailing, proxy.safeAreaInsets.trailing)
                            .overlay {
                                Text("\(element)").foregroundStyle(.white)
                            }
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, alignment: .center)
                            .id(element)
                    }
                })
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition, anchor: .center)
            .scrollTargetLayout()
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .horizontal)
            .scrollIndicators(.never)
            .animation(.smooth, value: scrollPosition)
            .onChange(of: scrollPosition, initial: true, { oldValue, newValue in
                print("oldValue: \(String(describing: oldValue)) --- newValue: \(String(describing: newValue))")
                guard let newValue, let oldValue else { return }
                
                if newValue == elements.last {
                    //swiped right
                    addNewElement(at: .next)
                    print("Add new element --> Next")
                }
                
                if newValue == elements.first {
                    //swiped left
                    addNewElement(at: .previous)
                    print("Add new element <-- Previous")
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    // Helper function to adjust the scroll position
    private func moveScrollPosition(by offset: Int) {
        if let current = scrollPosition {
            let newPosition = current + offset
            scrollPosition = newPosition
        }
    }
    
    private func addNewElement(at position: ScrollViewAppender) {
        switch position {
        case .next:
            let last = elements.last
            elements.append(last! + 1)
        case .previous:
            elements.insert(elements.first! - 1, at: 0) // Insert a new item at the start
        case .none:
            break
        }
    }
}


When you add a new entry to the start of the array, the ScrollView immediately shows it, so it becomes the active scroll position.
A workaround is to add the new item before changing position. Then restore the old scroll position, before moving to the new position. Moving to the new position needs to be performed later, that is, asynchronously, to allow the ScrollView to adjust to the restored position.
Try changing the "swipe left" button to the following:
Button {
    if let firstPosition = elements.first, scrollPosition == firstPosition + 1 {
        let oldScrollPosition = scrollPosition
        addNewElement(at: .previous)
        scrollPosition = oldScrollPosition
        Task { @MainActor in
            moveScrollPosition(by: -1)
        }
    } else {
        moveScrollPosition(by: -1)
    }
} label: {
    Text("swipe left")
}


Wow! Thank you very much! It works. I sadly cannot yet accept your answer as accepted because of my low reputation.

One issue I haven't been able to resolve: if the 'swipe left' button is clicked rapidly multiple times, the swipe animation fails to display.

It might help to block/ignore updates if they happen too soon after the previous one. The answer to Preserve Scroll Position in ScrollView when Adding New Items is using a similar technique (for a simlar issue of adding scrolled content).
